# Using highcharts with rails not displaying plotLines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using the High Charts library with rails using the gem found [here](https://github.com/agrobbin/highcharts-js-rails).  Everything is working very nicely, except when I try and add a plotLine to either axis, I can't seem to figure it out.  Here are the two options that I've tried so far and their results.  Any insight into what is happening would be much appreciated.

Option 1:

```
chart.yAxis([{title: 'Y-Axis', min: 0, plotLines: {value: 25}])
```

Result: I get an error in the JavaScript of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'concat'
```

Specifically, this is referencing the following code in highcharts.js

```
each((options.plotLines || []).concat(options.plotBands || []), function (plotLineOptions) {
    //plotLinesAndBands.push(new PlotLineOrBand(plotLineOptions).render());
    axis.addPlotBandOrLine(plotLineOptions);
});
```

When I pause the execution there the options.plotLines variable is an Object and not an Array, hence no concat method.

Option 2:

```
chart.yAxis([{title: '', min: 0, plotLines: [{value: 25}]}])
```

Result: The page fails to render with the following error message from Rails.

```
You must pass a Hash to Highcharts::Axis::PlotLines. You passed [{:value=>25}]
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, however, given the API documentation of [high charts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) I would of expected this to work, as I would like to give more than 1 plotLine.

I have also attempted to use chart.renderer.path but that has failed as well.  Can someone please explain what is going on, and hopefully suggest a way that I can draw a horizontal line across a High Charts graph in Rails with this gem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this out by manipulating the underlying javascript produced by the HighCharts ruby object.  Here is the code to do it

```
chart.yAxis([{title: '', min: 0, plot_lines_replace: plot_lines}])

# Because of a bug in this High Charts rails library, I'm going to have
# to add the plot_lines myself through the javascript

return chart.to_s.gsub("plot_lines_replace", "plotLines").html_safe
```

This will modify the plot_lines_replace string with plotLines in the javascript and it will work correctly.